# Algorithm for finding empty areas

Tags: algorithm, geometry

does anybody know of a good algorithm for this task:

- a multi polygon contains the reserved areas
- find an empty position for the given polygon which is closest to its original position but does not intersect the reserved areas

I have implemented some very basic algorithm which does the job but far from optimally.

Thank You!

**Edit:**

my solution basically does the following:

- move given polygon in all possible directions dx and dy
- check wether the new intersection is less than the previous intersection
- if so, use new position and make sure that you don't move your polygon back and forth at the same position
- repeat these steps a maximum of N times

Example: it is intended for placing text which should not overlap with each other.

Comment: If you have algorithms, Show us your attempts.

Comment: updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

One method that immediately pops into my mind is to shoot a ray (i.e. measure a line segment) from the original position to every vertex of the polygon. Do a comparison on those distances, and then based on those comparisons, narrow it down to the minimally far away line segment of the polygon. Compute the perpendicular intersection of that line with the origin, and you'll get the minimally far away point. If the vertex comparisons don't lead you down the right path, just shoot off lines in random directions, and just stop when you're happy with the result. It doesn't sound like you require optimality.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the original problem: making sure that one piece of text doesn't overlap another. Presumably this is for labelling a map. The way I do it is this: draw the text invisibly, checking for overlap (by using a specialised graphics context that instead of drawing a pixel, checks whether a pixel is already there) then try another position along the line on which the text is to be placed - usually a street. I try the middle of the line first, then successive positions further and further left and right of the middle. If that fails I try again with a condensed (narrower) font.